# Word for "A society/group/system that does not value aesthetics"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means  "a society/group/system that does not value aesthetics"?

I can't think of anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean 'politicians'?

Comment: *Crass* is an approximate suggestion; it may serve depending on context.

Comment: You might consider *Spartan*, who has a reputation for practically l, dedication to martial preparation, and stark minimalism.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is [*philistine:*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/philistine#philistine)

> NOUN
>
> A person who is hostile or indifferent to culture and the arts, or who has no understanding of them:
>
> *I am a complete philistine when it comes to paintings*
>
> *I'm a bit of philistine when it comes to art; I don't have much time for it and art galleries make me feel sleepy.*
>
> *Of course, I guess it's possible that these books are all pretty well known to literate Americans and I'm just a philistine.*
>
> *Ignore the doom-mongers and philistines - it is both possible and desirable to rescue Venice from sinking into the sea.*
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Hostile or indifferent to culture and the arts:
>
> *a philistine government*
>
> *there were displays to inspire even the most philistine of visitors*
>
> *Beneath this undercurrent of grumbling is the philistine assumption that it is elitist or irrelevant to consider art which does not excite the mass market.*
>
> *And as yet another example of perhaps the only serious British contribution to 20th century architecture faces demolition, is there any other art form about which we could be so utterly, wilfully philistine?*
>
> *The policy is philistine, expensive and environmentally disastrous.*

(Definitions and examples from oxforddictionaries.com)

Other possible words are *anti-intellectual* and *lowbrow.*

Comment: + 1 yes..that is the word!!

Comment: I am not sure if anti-intellectual or lowbrow would be right, I was probably going for a society that places excessive importance on "function/rigor over style/beauty" and the example in my mind was a society of mathematicians or physicists. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Pushpendre - If that's your focus, then **utilitarian** could be the best match. Macmillandictionary.com, for instance, defines *utilitarian* as "designed to be useful rather than attractive".

Comment: Or perhaps **functionalist**? From "the theory that the design of an object should be determined by its function rather than by aesthetic considerations", although there are other definitions that might muddy the waters a bit.